# Client hangs after completing wcf service call

Tags: wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF application calls WCF service method and and then wpf app hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236675/wpf-application-calls-wcf-service-method-and-and-then-wpf-app-hangs)

Service:

```
public MoviesResponse GetMoviesList(MoviesRequest request)
{
    List<Movie> movies = DataAccess.GetMovies(0);
    MoviesResponse response = new MoviesResponse();
    response.movies = movies;
    return response;
}

[DataContract]   
public class MovieResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public IList<MovieReview> movieReviews;
}

[DataContract]    
public class MoviesResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public IList<Movie> movies;
}

[DataContract]
public class MovieRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public int movieId;
}

[DataContract] 
public class MoviesRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public int movieId;
}
```

Client:

```
MoviesResponse response = Client.GetMoviesList(request);
```

Service call completes but never returns to the client.

Comment: Do you get no error message at all? And you are sure the server method completes? (and BTW, the server method doesn't do anything with the request object...)

Comment: I check in debugging and the call completes but the control doesnt return to client

Comment: I think you'll need to post your full server-side code including the data contracts.

Comment: I have edited with the datacontracts

Comment: Change the `IList<>` to `List<>` in your data contracts. The receiving end doesn't know what to do with an `IList<>`, it must know what type to instantiate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19098/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-roy-dictus)

Comment: What do you mean by _"never returns to the client"_? What does a tool like Fiddler say, does any data get transferred? Is Visual Studio "Running" or "Debugging"? Are client and service in the same solution?

Comment: I am debugging the application and the control never returns to the client

Comment: Lets start this discussion via chat

Comment: Client and Service are in  the same solution