# WPF application calls WCF service method and and then wpf app hangs

Tags: wcf

I have a wpf application which calls a wcf service method. The method runs fine in debugging mode but the method doesnt return back to the client call.

```
Here is the code.
Client:
public class Provider
    {
        private static ActionServiceClient Client { get; set; }
        static Provider()
        {
            Client = new ActionServiceClient();
        }

        public UserResponse GetUsers(UserRequest request)
        {
            UserResponse resp = new UserResponse();
            resp = Client.GetUsers(request);
            return resp;
        }
    }
WCF Service :
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
    public class ActionService : IActionService
    {
        public MovieResponse GetReviews(MovieRequest request)
        {
            List<MovieReview> reviews = DataAccess.GetMovieReviews(0);
            MovieResponse response = new MovieResponse();
            response.movieReviews = reviews;
            return response;
        }

        public UserResponse GetUsers(UserRequest request)
        {
            List<User> users = DataAccess.GetUsers(0);
            UserResponse resp = new UserResponse();
            resp.users = users;
            return resp;
        }

[DataContract]
    public class UserResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<User> users;
    }

[DataContract]
    public class UserRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int userId;
    }
```

I run the program in debug mode and after completion of the service call the wpf application hangs....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Client hangs after completing wcf service call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235010/client-hangs-after-completing-wcf-service-call)

Comment: I found the answer. It's because I have an image that contains byte[] (Image Column). So the wpf app hangs.

Comment: Please can you post this as the answer so others can find it. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops....Passing an image is not allowed.